# [A]Type cannot be cast to [B]Type of matching assembly versions

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, designer

Just recently I started getting this weird error, it's only problem in Designer, the app runs with no problems.

I've tried

- clearing the shadow cache
- removing bin/obj folder
- rebuilding solution
- removing and re-adding the mentioned assembly and doing all above again

This is the complete error

```
[A]MahApps.Metro.Controls.MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl cannot be cast to 
[B]MahApps.Metro.Controls.MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl. 
Type A originates from 'MahApps.Metro, Version=1.1.3.174, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Designer\ShadowCache\x2tfp5zd.b23\jgke2cb5.0ws\tmp\MahApps.Metro.dll'.
Type B originates from 'MahApps.Metro, Version=1.1.3.174, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Designer\ShadowCache\majxo3bg.w3c\dwou5m4n.p1u\MahApps.Metro.dll'.
HeRgoT  C:\Users\usr\MyProject\MyProject\MainWindow.xaml
```

Any idea what the cause is?

Comment: Try to sign assembly with strong name.

Comment: Quick note, when I replace the control with a different one from the same assembly the issue disappears

Comment: I've had this problem when the target framework of a referenced project was different (4.5 vs 4.5.2).

Comment: @Herman oh, since MahApps is opensource I'll try building it against 4.6 (.net version my project uses)

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem this was caused by multiple copies of mahapps.metro.dll in shadow cache folder and to fix this what I did was:
1. Uninstall mahapps.metro.dll as reference to the project
2. Close Visual Studio
3. Clear Shadow cache folder, then restart VS.